# UI freezing problem in c# 2.0

Tags: c#

Sometimes I saw that when I call a method from my form to do something that my UI freezes. How to solve this problem? If I call that method in separate thread then problem will be solved?

If I call method in separate thread like the code below

```
new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
{
  HeavyMethod();
}).Start();
```

does this solve my problem or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the method on a Background Worker would be the best solution.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Doing that you can control when things get updated (using the **Report Progress** Feature) and allow you to cancel the work.

Also, make sure that whatever resources you manipulate in the `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` are properly shared.  You can get into what is called "Race Conditions" which causes your output to be non-determanistic (e.g. you won't get the same results every time you run the method)

For a good walk through on Multithreading and shared resources, see this link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/multithreadingintro10062005000439am/multithreadingintro.aspx?articleid=920ecafc-e83b-4a9c-a64d-0b39ad885705

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` was definitely in WinForms .Net 2.0.

Comment: Actually, it's 2.0 and up. Also note that it is a feature of .Net, not C#. In fact, there is no version 3.5 of the C# language (VS 2008 shipped with C# 3.0 and .Net 3.5).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=VS.80).aspx that is the MSDN Documentation for .net 2.0.  Oh and .net 2.0 is basically the same thing as .net 3.5 EXCEPT .net 3.5 has a bunch of syntactical sugar added.  This is why you can host .net 3.5 web apps on a .net 2.0 web server.  All the code compiles down to the same IL.  Here is a thread that explains the differences: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/netfxbcl/thread/381753d5-4497-4324-bc86-7fea63f7cb24

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling your method in response to an event, then by default the method will be running on the GUI thread (the thread that the runtime uses to handle all user events). If that method is huge and/or heavy, then it will "freeze" the UI as you describe.

Making it run on a separate thread *is* a viable solution for many of these cases.

There are cases, however, when you'll actually want the UI to "block" (for example, if you are updating a lot of controls, you don't want the user to mess with them in the meanwhile). For such cases, the sanest approach is to pop up a *modal* "wait" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is C# 2.0, I suppose it is WinForms.  Don't hold up the UI thread with CPU-bound code.

You can spawn a new thread to run your CPU-bound code, but you have to be careful not to access WinForms controls, especially not to update control properties.  Many WinForms controls can only be accessed/updated from the UI thread.  Check the InvokeRequired field to see if you need to marshal (i.e. use Invoke) the call from another thread back to the UI thread.

Also consider using the ThreadPool instead of creating a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, If you move the heavy processing off of the UI Thread then it should free up the UI to redraw. For what you want to do your implementation should work just fine. Although ThreadPooling or BackgroundWorker would be the suggested implementations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=VS.80).aspx), (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).